# Angular + RxJS: repeat the request on status code 202

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a simple request that I would like to repeat in case the response is with status **202**. Currently, it looks like this:

```
this.http.get(endPoint, {
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: this.headers
})
.map((response: Response) => {
    return response.text() ? response.json() : '';
})
.catch((error) => this.handleError(error));
```

I have tried with `.repeatWhen()` but unfortunately, I don't receive the `Response` object and I cannot set a validation by the status code.

Any ideas how can I do that?

Comment: How come you didn't receive the `Response` object in `repeatWhen()` when you're using it in `.map()`?

Comment: In `repeatWhen()` I receive a `Subject` object, not the `Response`... can you present your idea with plunker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a misunderstanding of how `repeatWhen()` works. The callback to this operator receives a single parameter which is an Observable where it pushes an empty item when the source completes. So it's not ideal for you (because you don't have access to the Response object you need).

You could use `retryWhen()` instead:

```
this.http.get(endPoint, { withCredentials: true, headers: this.headers })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        if (response.code === 202) {
            throw response;
        }
        return response;
    })
    .map((response: Response) => {
        return response.text() ? response.json() : '';
    })
    .retryWhen(obs => {
        return obs; // always just resubscribe without any further logic
    });
```

This throws the `response` as an error which is then caught by `retryWhen` that just resubscribes. You could of course use more logic to control if you resubscribe, for example:

```
.retryWhen(obs => {
   return obs.filter(...);
});
```

Comment: Nice solution. But in this case, if for example, the response is 404 it will re-subscribe and will execute the API call again. How can I avoid that... to recall for only 202?

Comment: @HristoEftimov That's what I mentioned at the end. The error is pushed to the Observable `obs` where you can filter only the error you want.

Answer (score 3):

Use this for Rx 6. This retries the 202 up to 3 times, and throws a timeout error at the end of the third try.

```js
@Injectable()
export class ProgressInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(req).pipe(
            map(t => {
                if (t['status'] === 202) {
                    throw 202;
                }
                return t;
            }),
            retryWhen(t => {
                return t.pipe(
                    concatMap((e, i) => {
                        if (e !== 202) {
                            return throwError(e);
                        }
                        return iif(
                            () => i >= 2,
                            throwError(new Error('Operation Timed Out!')),
                            of(e).pipe(delay(1000))
                        )
                    })
                )
            }),
        );    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as `retryWhen()` is deprecated and will be removed in v9 or v10, below is an updated answer; reference: [retryWhen](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/retryWhen)

Use `retry()` with it's `delay` option.

> Will be removed in v9 or v10, use retry's delay option instead. Will be removed in v9 or v10. Use retry's delay option instead. Instead of retryWhen(() => notify$), use: retry({ delay: () => notify$ }).

```
@Injectable()
export class RetryInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor() {}

  shouldRetry(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.status >= 300) {
      throw error;
    }
    return timer(30);
  }

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<unknown>) => {
        if (response.status === 204) {
          throw 204;
        }
        return response;
      }),
      retry({ count: 1000, delay: this.shouldRetry })
    );
  }
}
```

Retry count and status code can be changed to suit scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can make http call again in the **catch** method

```js
.catch(res => {
    return res.status === 202?
        this.http.get(endPoint):
        Observable.throw(res);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using flatMap:

```
.flatMap((response:Response) => {
    if (response.status === 200) {
        return Observable.of(this.mapResponse(response.json()));
    } else if (response.status === 202) {
        return this.http.get(endPoint, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: this.headers
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: This is also an option. But I need to create a function for `this.http.get()` because the repeated request can return 202 again and again :)

For that, I am searching for a better solution.